# Visibility property not updated through binding with RadioButton

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I have two XAML objects which I'd like to change the visibility of with the status of radio buttons. However I cannot get them to work. I've gone through the "Similar Questions" for this which haven't managed to make a fix.

For both of these the command is definitely triggering - I put a breakpoint on UpdateVisibility to check, and the switch statement is working as expected.

### First attempt - Visibility Binding

This did nothing, and without the FallbackValue would display both elements (even though the Visibilities are set in the constructor.

Properties:

```
public Visibility TreeViewVisibility { get; set; }
public Visibility ContentViewVisibility { get; set; }
```

Command:

```
public ICommand VisibilityCommand
{
    get { return visibilityCommand ?? (visibilityCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateVisibility)); }
}

public void UpdateVisibility(object o)
{
    switch (o.ToString())
    {
        case "XMLView":
            Console.WriteLine("XMLView");
            TreeViewVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            ContentViewVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            break;
        case "TextView":
            Console.WriteLine("TextView");
            TreeViewVisibility = Visibility.Collapsed;
            ContentViewVisibility = Visibility.Visible;
            break;
    }
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TreeViewVisibility));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ContentViewVisibility));
}
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="xmlTree" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource treeViewTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Document}" Height="600" Visibility="{Binding TreeViewVisibility, FallbackValue=Visible}"/>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Visibility="{Binding ContentViewVisibility, FallbackValue=Collapsed}" Height="600"/>
...
<RadioButton GroupName="DisplayType" Command="{Binding VisibilityCommand}" CommandParameter="XMLView" IsChecked="True" Content="XML View" Margin="0,0,5,0"/>
<RadioButton GroupName="DisplayType" Command="{Binding VisibilityCommand}" CommandParameter="TextView" Content="Text View" Margin="5,0,0,0"/>
```

### Second Attempt - Data Trigger

I then attempted to set it as a data trigger, by changing the properties to booleans (and the related things in the ViewModel). This caused the default view to be the TreeView, and the TextBlock is collapsed as default, but the visibilities did not change on clicking radio buttons.

Properties:

```
public bool TreeViewVisibility { get; set; }
public bool ContentViewVisibility { get; set; }
```

Command:

```
public ICommand VisibilityCommand
{
    get { return visibilityCommand ?? (visibilityCommand = new RelayCommand(UpdateVisibility)); }
}

public void UpdateVisibility(object o)
{
    switch (o.ToString())
    {
        case "XMLView":
            Console.WriteLine("XMLView");
            TreeViewVisibility = true;
            ContentViewVisibility = false;
            break;
        case "TextView":
            Console.WriteLine("TextView");
            TreeViewVisibility = true;
            ContentViewVisibility = false;
            break;
    }
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(TreeViewVisibility));
    OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ContentViewVisibility));
}
```

XAML:

```
<TreeView Name="xmlTree" ItemTemplate="{StaticResource treeViewTemplate}" ItemsSource="{Binding Document}" Height="600">
    <TreeView.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TreeView">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TreeViewVisibility}" Value="false">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TreeView.Style>
</TreeView>
<TextBlock Text="{Binding Content}" Height="600">
    <TextBlock.Style>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Collapsed"/>
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ContentViewVisibility}" Value="true">
                    <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </TextBlock.Style>
</TextBlock>
```

Comment: For a start, `DataTrigger Binding="{Binding TreeViewVisibility}" Value="false"` cannot work because `TreeViewVisibility` is of type `Visibility` and not `Boolean`.

Comment: @CorentinPane I didn't want to just duplicate the code; for the DataTrigger part I changed the TreeViewVisibility  and ContentViewVisibility to booleans, and changed the command to set them to true/false instead, just with the same names. I'll put the changed code into the question for clarity.

Comment: Your view model should have a *single* boolean property that enables either the one or the other view. Then using DataTriggers would be easy. You would also not have an ICommand, but just bind the IsChecked property of one of the RadioButtons to the bool view model property.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do that all in your XAML without needing any binding to your view model, using `DataTrigger` like you started to:

```xml
<StackPanel>
    <TextBlock Text="XML View" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=radio1, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBlock Text="Text View" Margin="5">
        <TextBlock.Style>
            <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
                <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Hidden"/>
                <Style.Triggers>
                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding ElementName=radio2, Path=IsChecked}" Value="True">
                        <Setter Property="Visibility" Value="Visible"/>
                    </DataTrigger>
                </Style.Triggers>
            </Style>
        </TextBlock.Style>
    </TextBlock>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radio1" GroupName="DisplayType" IsChecked="True" Content="XML View" Margin="5"/>
    <RadioButton x:Name="radio2" GroupName="DisplayType" Content="Text View" Margin="5"/>
</StackPanel>
```

You can read more about `ElementName` binding in [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.elementname).

Comment: You can read more [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.ui.xaml.data.binding.elementname)

Comment: out of curiosity - do you know how I would use the radio button value in a ViewModel. For instance, I would like a Copy to Clipboard button, but what gets copied depends on whether it's currently in XML View or Text View?

Comment: you can still bind the IsChecked property of the radiobutton to a viewmodel's property, independently from the ElementName binding.